# How to store a NSSet (one-to-many) using Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, store, nsset

I am wondering how I can programmatically update a Core Data object. The object is a NSSet though. So I can summarize this with the scheme below:

```
Property
---------
name
price
typology

Property_has_typology
---------------------
typology_id
property
```

There is a one-to-many relationship between the Property and Property_has_typology. As one property might have several typologies (aka categories) such as Bed & Breakfast, Villa, Hotel, Mansion, Country House.

So I let the user select multiple rows in my TableView and when he clicks **save** I want to store these changes. So I do:

```
NSMutableArray *storeItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Get selected items
for (int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++) {
     Properties_has_typology *typo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Properties_has_typology" 
                                                                    inManagedObjectContext: [PropertyProvider sharedPropertyProvider].context];
     typo.typology_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt: (int)[items objectAtIndex:i]];
     typo.property = property;
     [storeItems addObject: typo];
}

//Store the items for the Property and save it
if ([storeItems count] > 0) {
    NSLog(@"Going to save...");
    NSSet *storeSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:storeItems];
    property.typology = storeSet;

    [property save];

    [storeSet release];
}
```

This kinda works, the issue though is that it doesn't really update the existing values. It just overrides it. So if I save the same two items **twice** (just as an example) I'd get the following in my database:

```
PK  TYPOLOGY
------------
1 | 
2 |   
3 |  4
4 |  6
```

So yes they are being stored, but it also creates empty rows (clears them instead of deleting/updating them).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//call 
NSArray* oldTypos = [property.typology allObjects];
[[property removeTypology:[PropertyProvider sharedPropertyProvider].context];
[[property addTypology:storeSet];
for(int i = 0; i < [oldTypos count]; i++){
[[PropertyProvider sharedPropertyProvider].context deleteObject:[oldTypos:objectAtIndex:i]];
}
Error* error = nil;
if(![[PropertyProvider sharedPropertyProvider].context save:&error]){
abort();
}
//Also, rename the to-many relationship to plural.
```

Apologies of there are any typos. I am on my windows machine at the moment so I cannot check it.

Comment: It seems like the `deleteObject` is indeed actually the thing I was looking for. Now I can delete all entries entirely and insert new ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***TechZen says:** I just noticed after the fact that I reversed the to-many relationship that the parent described. However, everything works the same way. I'll edit when I find time.*

You are working to hard by doing things manually that Core Data does automatically. To set a  relationship you just set one side of it and the managed object context sets the other automatically.

So, if you have a data model like this:

```
Property{
    typology<<-->Property_has_typology.properties
}

Property_has_typology{
    properties<-->>Property.typology
}
```

Then to set the the relationship from the `Property` object side you just use:

```
aPropertyObject.typology=aProperty_has_typologyObject;
```

To set if from the `Property_has_typology` object side you use the relationship accessor methods in the implementation (.m) that Core Data generated for you:

```
[aProperty_has_typologyObject addPropertiesObject:aPropertyObject];
```

or

```
[aProperty_has_typologyObject addPropertiesObjects:aSetOfPropertyObjects];
```

... and you are done.

Core Data wouldn't provide much utility if you had to manage all the object relationships by hand.

Comment: Yes I have set all these functionalities, but the thing is that when I use these methods, it still stores references to the other ones in the database. So I do `[property addTypologyObject: typo];` but that just seems to **add** it. Even when doing `[property removeTypology: property.typology];` (should remove the entire set of Typology references imo) it still keeps records in the database like described in my question.

Comment: Removing an object from a relationship doesn't delete it, it just severs the relationship. If you want to delete an object, you need to use `[NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject:]`

Comment: When you used a method called `addTypologyObject` what did you expect to happen? I think you are misunderstanding something critical about Core Data. Neither of the methods you mention work like you seem to think they should.

Comment: I expect `addTypologyObject` to add the Typology I declared to my property. So as there doesn't seem to be a way to update the property set (auto delete existing and add new ones) I guess first I'll have to `deleteObject` and then `addTypologyObject`..?

Comment: `addTypologyObject` will add a single Typology object to the relationship `removeTypologyObject:` will remove a single object. `addTypologyObjects:` will add the contents of a set of Typology objects to the relationship whereas ` removeTypologyObjects:` will remove those Typology objects from the relationship.  None of the methods creates or destroys the Typology objects themselves. They must exist before they are added and they still exist after they are removed. If you want to delete a managed object you have to tell the context to delete it. Nothing else deletes objects.